# How to init WordPress from a cronjob?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I used to initiate WordPress in my cronjobs by calling something like:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__);
$file = substr($file,0,stripos($file,"wp-content"));

require($file."/wp-load.php");
```

But this isn't working anymore. If I use a test script in the same directory, for example:

```
require($file."/testscript.php");
```

It executes without a problem. I also have no problem running the script directly. It's only when it's run from the cronjob.

There are no errors being thrown to indicate a permission or path problem.

So what's happening? Is wp-load.php actively failing due to being called from a cronjob?

Comment: Can you use wget instead of php cli ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304811/initialize-wordpress-environment-in-a-script-to-be-run-by-a-cron-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to trace the issue back to the way I was handling WP login authentication during the init action hook. So, wasn't WordPress' or cronjob's fault.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm assuming you have a longer job to run, or something needs to happen out of public view; which is why you're attempting to instantiate WP from outside it's home directory, and not use wget to access WP via the normal wp-cron.php.

If that's the case

```
define("WP_USE_THEMES",false);
require("/path/to/wp/wp-load.php");

if (defined("ABSPATH")) {

    /** Do something */
}
```

...should to the job

If you're trying to access WP from inside a plugin folder, it can be a little trickier; in which case something like this might work:

```
if(!defined('ABSPATH') || !defined('WPINC')) {
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE); 

    $levels = 4; // Number of levels up, to the wp-load.php file
    require_once dirname(__FILE__, $levels)."/wp-load.php";
}
```